# How to remove a value from averaged number

Tags: math, average

My requirement is, every time I need to calculate the average value for the provided cost. Currently I am using the following formula to calculate it:

Average cost = (previous_average_cost + cost_value)/2

After adding 5 to 6 cost_value, I need to remove one of the cost_value from the average cost. Currently I thinking how to remove the added cost_value from the average cost. Please share your thoughts.

For example:

```
Step:1
previous_average_cost = 0
cost_value = 10
average cost = (0+10)/2 = 5

Step:2 
previous_average_cost = 5
cost_value = 15
average cost = (5+15)/2 = 10

Step:3 
previous_average_cost = 10
cost_value = 20
average cost = (10+20)/2 = 15
```

Finally now the average cost is 15: I need to remove the previously added cost_value = 15 from the current average cost 15. Please share your thoughts

Comment: That isn't really averaging.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Do we have any solution for this

Comment: The problem isn't well defined. Do you want the value to be what it would have been without a step 2 in there. Eg. just a step1 then step 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
Average cost = (previous_average_cost + cost_value)/2
```

Let's review the definition of average:

```
x(ave) = sum(x)/N
```

where N = # of points.

If you add one more point:

```
x(new_ave) = (N*x(ave) + y)/(N+1)
```

You have to hang onto the current average and number of points to be able to update.

If you remove a point you've added:

```
x(new_ave) = (N*x(ave) - y)/(N-1)
```

Comment: Average is a pretty colloquial term, OP could be doing a moving average. Although in that case, it isn't clear what "removing a previous point" would cause.